# Spring inject interface implementation

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, interface

I'd like to use lombok to inject a class implemented from a interface like below:

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @_(@Inject))
public class className {
    @NonNull
    private final ClassA1 a1 implements ClassA;
    ...
}
```

But obviously this is not working, so what's the correct way to do this?

=================

edit: 
Or should I do this way?

```
public class className {
        private ClassA a1;
        public className(A1 a1) {
        this.a1 = a1; }
    }
```

===================
Here's the code after taking advice from Mykhailo Moskura:

```
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @_(@Inject))
public class C {
     @NonNull
     private A b;
     public someFunction() {
        b.method();
     }
}
```

Here A is the interface, while b is Class implementing A with camelcase name. And using lombok I injected b, and now call some method of b in some function. However I realized b.method still points to the interface A, but not B.

Comment: Just make the type the interface instead of the class, that is the whole point of having an interface. So `private final ClassA a1` instead of `private final ClassA1 a1`.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. But after inject "private final ClassA a1", I'd like to specify a1 as ClassA1, what should I do? (sth like:  private List<String> l, then l = new ArrayList<>())

Comment: `ClassA1` is a `ClassA` because it implements that interface.

Comment: Yes, definitely. But what should I do, if I'd like to specifically use ClassA1 later on? Can I sth like a1 = new ClassA1(); ?

Comment: Yes you can, as stated `ClassA1` is a `ClassA` . That is basic Java...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@NonNull is not required 
Lombok will generate a constructor with fields that are marked as final or @NonNull
You can autowire just declaring the interface type
and giving the implementation class name in camel case starting from lower case.
Also you need to declare your implementation as bran and the class in which you are injecting it too.
@Inject is java ee CDI dependency.
@Autowired is spring specific.
Spring supports both but it says to use @Autowired
Here is an example:

```
public interface A{
}

@Component
public class B implements A{
}

@Component
public class C {
  private A a;
@Autowired
  public C(A a){
   this.a = a;  
}
}
```

Lombok sample:

```
 @RequiredArgsConstructor
   @Component
    public class C {
      //Here it will inject the implementation of A interface with name of implementation (As we have name of impl B we declare field as b , if HelloBeanImpl then helloBeanImpl
     private A b;
    }
```

But if you have many implementations of one interface you can use @Qualifier with name of bean or the above sample with lombok where A b where b is the name of implementation

Comment: "autowire just declaring the interface type and giving the implementation class name", how can I do this?

Comment: Thanks for your code, I guess "private B b" should be "private A b" ?

Comment: Here is a list of examples https://www.baeldung.com/spring-injection-lombok

Comment: Thanks. Still confused by your lombok sample "private A b",  A is interface name, while b is simply a random name. So how can A know it's class B that's implementing A?

Comment: b - is the name of implementation class starting from lower case (using CamelCase)
For example if i had interface HelloWorld and class implementing it HelloWorldImpl i need to write helloWorldImpl

Comment: Here is link with completely explanation how @Autowire works:
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-autowire

Comment: OMG, thanks so much, now I understand. I'm so surprised we could do this way!  However, first I didn't see such magic methods using CamelCase from the reference link you gave. Second, what if I have class "DDBAccessor" implementing "Accessor", then I should write as "ddbAccessor" or "dDBAccessor"?

Comment: I think you should try this one : ddbAccessor
Here is the link about camel case https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case

Comment: Thanks a lot. One final question: I tried using CamelCase (b) for the Class B as you suggested, but when I tried to call method of "b", the method still points to the interface A but not Class B. So I'm doubting if I'm doing it right

Comment: it would be something like A a = new B();
a.someMethod();
It would take an implementation of B

Comment: Thx. I put what I wrote in the edits, can you have a look? Maybe I'm missing sth.

Comment: I think its fine , b.method is still pointing to Interface A  but the implementation is pointing to class B

Comment: Because i need to use certain method of b.  I first inject b, and call its method.

Comment: Okey its fine)
Thanks)